# Two locations not working in nginx for MERN application

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have nginx configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen[::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html/ericwu-trademarket/frontend/build;

    location /backend/ {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;   #backend in node js
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;       #front end in react js
    }
}
```

the front end is running properly. But by running backend like this **http://server-ip-address/backend** it is showing cannot get /backend/.

Where might I be mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

**Check UFW port Allow in server**

Check status of UFW:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

If not show 8000/tcp as a Allow then allow it:

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Obviously you are trying to use Websokets**.

When it comes to best practices, is better to have the backend services defined inside an upstream definition. You are trying to proxy requests to "localhost:8000" but localhost translates to ip 127.0.0.1. If that is not the ip address of the nodejs app, then is pretty normal that your config won't work.

Nginx expects a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), or ip addresses list of backend servers to work properly.

That being said, your config should be:

```
http {
    upstream backend_server {
        #least_conn; #Loadbalancing method in case you want to use multiple backends
        #ip_hash; 
        server backend1.example.com:8000; #or IP address
       }
    
    server {
      server_name _;
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen[::]:80 default_server;
      root /var/www/html/ericwu-trademarket/frontend/build;
      
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /backend {
            proxy_pass http://backend_server;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # WebSocket specific
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            # For long running HTTP requests, don't buffer up the
            # response from origin servers but send them directly to the client.
            proxy_buffering  off;

        }
    }
}
```